# Matplotlib path arc/curve tangent to adjacent lines with Matplotlib's path and patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, patch

I have an arc defined by several points of known coordinates. The arc is tangent to both of its neighboring lines again defined with two end known end points. I attempted to generate a plot using Matplotlib's path and patches functions. Since I could not directly use the arc center point, I used another point on the arc (arc's center point) along with its two end points. However, the resulting arc doesn't seem to be tangent to the adjacent lines and doesn't look to be a circular arc. Is there a way to achieve a circular looking arc tangent to neighboring lines with Matplotlib path and patches? Following are my code and a visual.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as Patches

verts = [
    (57.000000, 0.000000), # P0
    (57.000000, 6.500000), # P1
    (56.000000, 6.500000), # P2
    (54.608163, 2.675960), # P3
    (53.832652, 1.692228), # P4
    (52.624106, 1.362741), # P5
    (30.000000, 3.575370), # P7
    (30.000000, 0.000000), # P8
    (57.000000, 0.000000) # P0
    ]

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CURVE3,
         Path.CURVE3,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO
         ]

path = Path(verts, codes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = Patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='blue', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(25,60)
ax.set_ylim(-0.2,20)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `matplotlib` to build an arc with `Path.arc`, and put lines tangent to the end points on either end.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

# get bezier curves for arc
arc = Path.arc(0, 90)

# attach straight lines
vertices = np.vstack([[[1.05, -1],
                       [1, -1]],
                      arc.vertices,
                      [[-1, 1],
                       [-1, 1.05],
                       [1.05, 1.05],
                       [0,0]]])

codes = ([Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO]
         + list(arc.codes[1:])
         + [Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.CLOSEPOLY])

# translate
xt = 0
yt = 0

# and rotate
transform = Affine2D().rotate_deg(30).translate(1,2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch = PathPatch(Path(vertices, codes).transformed(transform))
ax.add_patch(patch)

# make sure we can see it
axlim = 1.1 * 2 ** 0.5 
ax.set_xlim(-axlim + 1, axlim + 1)
ax.set_ylim(-axlim + 2, axlim + 2)

# make it look like a circle
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

giving

[image: figure showing 90 deg arc with ends extended in straight line segments]

Comment: Thanks @Rory Yorke, however I couldn't get this to work for me. It seems, this code creates an arc at default center (0, 0) and lines. Then, patches the lines and arc. Later, it translates the whole patch to a given point. It seems that I would need to plot the whole shape around the default arc center of (0, 0); line end point needs to be calculated based on this center, and then whole shape should be transformed. My shape can have multiple arcs, so it further complicates transformation. Being able the create arcs with the already already available center point would be great.